# Cookie. How can I count each page visit no duplicate?

Tags: database, cookies, count

My page URL is with 3 variables: id=N, num=N and item=N ; N = 1, 100. They are integers and an example of URL's given:

```
page.php?id=1&num=24&item=12
```

I want to count the visit with no duplicates. How I think it's should work:

If cookie exist don't add a new value to database, else set cookie and increment value in database.

I used a $_COOKIE[''] array, to identify if page was visited:

```
$_COOKIE['product[id]'] = $_GET['id'];
$_COOKIE['product[num]'] = $_GET['num'];
$_COOKIE['product[item]'] = $_GET['item'];
```

The problem appeared when the path it's different:

```
page.php?id=1&num=24&item=12&page=0#topView
```

I can't query the data base each time when a person access the page, it's because there are, 1000+ unique visits.

My questions is: how can I count in mod unique each page visit?

Note:

```
page.php?id=1&num=24&item=12
```

or

```
page.php?id=1&num=24&item=15
```

or

```
page.php?id=2&num=24&item=12
```

these links gives me an unique product info, depending by variables.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you thought about what happens if I go to your page and type page.php?id=2&num=10000000&item=12 ? :)

Comment: Yes, before any query, or any execution I added a block of filters to prevent any attack or data damage.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the meaning of the numbers. "I can't query the data base each time when a person access the page, it's because there are, 1000+ unique visits." - I doubt you can. In my opinion - you should. Count all the page accesses and when you want to grab the final results, do grouping by ip, id, num, item. Putting all the data into the database will also give you a brief view of the most popular pages. Even further, you will be able to see what pages are being accessed more times by one unique user and identify the reasons. The more data is better. It won't take much of your database.

Comment: Because every variable is different i made an unique identifier for each visitor by getting IP address:

md5($_GET['id'].$_GET['num'].$_GET['item']); // for session column
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if these 2 match it means the person was on page so I don't need to update the view column.

Thank Andrius !

Comment: Posted updated as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment is the solution for your problem, I am converting it as an aswer.

"I can't query the data base each time when a person access the page, it's because there are, 1000+ unique visits." - I doubt you can. In my opinion - you should. Count all the page accesses and when you want to grab the final results, do grouping by ip, id, num, item. Putting all the data into the database will also give you a brief view of the most popular pages. Even further, you will be able to see what pages are being accessed more times by one unique user and identify the reasons. The more data is better. It won't take much of your database.

There is a mistake in your finally decided algorithm. Imagine the id is 11, num is 5 and item is 7. And another with id = 1, num = 15, item = 7. Hope you see what I mean. :P Put it like that

```
md5($_GET['id'].'-'.$_GET['num'].'-'.$_GET['item']);
```

so it is really unique.